# Notifications not staying on screen

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, notification-icons

Im trying to setup notifications for a colleague whos got an Android phone (sorry dont know the OS off the top of my head).

The notifications im trying to set up are for the Trello.com app (but i presume the process would be the same for all notifications)

At the moment if they get a message on the app a notification pops up on the Android home screen, but soon disappears. It does not add a little icon next to the main App icon to indicate that there has been a notification / message. The notification also doesn't sit on their lock screen.

Is there a way i can change this so that they will get a notification alert sitting over the app icon and the notification will sit on their lock screen.

Comment: Seems you are used to the way iOS handles notifications... I assume you want the corner unread count badge, which is a function of some (mostly 3rd-party) launchers, e.g. Nova Launcher + TeslaUnread. As for the lockscreen, it *does* sit there normally by default, so we won't know what's wrong until we know the phone's brand and model.

Comment: If it really is a notification (and not e.g. a toast), it will sit in the notification bar on top of the screen. You can swipe that open with your finger (tap-and-hold the bar, then drag it down), and there it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like `toast message notification`
A toast provides simple feedback about an operation in a small popup.

Toasts automatically disappear after a timeout set by the app developers. So you can not control the behavior of toast messages.

[image]